# "SQLite does not support autoincrement for composite primary keys" after upgrading SQLAlchemy from 0.8 to 1.1

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

After upgrading from SQLAlchemy 0.8.4 to 1.1.5, I get the following error. What changed in SQLAlchemy to cause this? How do I fix it?

```
CompileError: (in table 'flights', column 'id'): SQLite does not support autoincrement for composite primary keys
```

```
class Flights(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'flights'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    departure = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('airport.id'), primary_key=True)
    arrival   = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('airport.id'), primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That primary key doesn't make sense. There's no point in making the two foreign keys part of the primary, it will already be unique just by virtue of the autoincrement.

If you want to make sure the airports were different, then use a check constraint. If you want to make searching by airports fast, create an index over the columns.

As to the error, the check for cases where autoincrement and composite keys were used with SQLite [was added in 1.1](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/commit/414af7b61291b3fa77eb6da6a9b123399214089b#diff-79c290956ad49825a085d3073170ca03R862), with a related [explanation in the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/migration_11.html#the-autoincrement-directive-is-no-longer-implicitly-enabled-for-a-composite-primary-key-column). It likely didn't do what you expected before, but didn't raise an error.